# Joining a collection based on members of the type

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava, method-chaining

I have a class A and its members b and c.
Now I construct the `List<A>` with this:

```
add(new A().setb("abcd").setc("123456"));
add(new A().setb("efgh").setc("789101"));
add(new A().setb("ijkl").setc("112345"));
```

I want to transform this List to string which looks like this

```
abcd,123456
efgh,789101
ijkl,112345
```

Now the very obvious way would be to have a `StringBuilder` and iterate across the List. Now I want to establish this using `Guava Joiner` like

```
Joiner.on("\n").skipNulls().join(.......)
```

the `join()` method expects an iterable. Can I somehow pass `A.getb(),A.getc()` Will `Iterables.transform` help?

Comment: You can first transform each `A` to a `String` by joining its members with `,`. Collect those results into a `List`. Then join the `String` values in that list with a `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!!

Lets say the `List<A>` is called `Alist`

```
String join=Joiner.on("\n").skipNulls().join(Iterables.transform(Alist, new Function<A,String>(){
            public String apply(A input){
                return input.getb()+","+input.getc();
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you can use

```
String result = as.stream().map((a) -> a.b + ',' + a.c).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

which first generates a `String` from each `A` element in the `List`, then collects it into a `String` by joining the individual `String` values with a new line character.

With Guava, you get something similar with

```
String result = Joiner.on('\n').join(Iterables.transform(as, (a) -> a.b + ',' + a.c));
```

assuming `as` is your `List<A>`.

Comment: Thanks. However I didnt know Guava supports the -> operator

Comment: @AbhiroopSarkar Guava is just a library. It's written in Java. Since Java 8, the syntax contains lambda expressions. You can use it with any code.

Comment: Oh! I thought you were writing the Guava expression in Java 6. Because I myself am using Java 6. Forgot to mention that. However I dont see there is much point of using the functional constructs of Guava in Java 8 provided the language now itself supports lambda expressions. However can you please tell me in my current answer, if its computationally more intensive or less or same compared to the simple way of StringBuilder? I think Iterables does lazy evaluation.

Comment: @AbhiroopSarkar At such a high level, it will be equivalent. Unless you're doing this computation millions of times a second, you'll see no difference.